# Messing with pointers and casts

Tags: types, arduino

I am using an API to send data throug a wireless module, but I am struggling with the types, and therefore I think I am not able to send out the data, could you give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

```
// define data to send
  char data[] = "00";

  // Getting Temperature that is 28.75
  float temperature = RTC.getTemperature();

  // HEADER,void float2String(float fl, char str[], int N);
  Utils.float2String (temperature, data, 2);

  // HEADER,uint8_t str2hex(char* str);
  uint8_t dataAux[4];

  dataAux= (char) Utils.str2hex( data);

  USB.println(dataAux);
  // HEADER,sendRadio(char * message)
  error = sendRadio(dataAux);
```

Then I got this compiler error:

```
    txP2PTemp.pde: In function 'void loop()':
    txP2PTemp.pde:572:31: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' to 'uint16_t* [3] {aka unsigned int* [3]}'
    txP2PTemp.pde:576:36: error: no matching function for call to 'W::sendRadio(uint16_t* [3])'
note: uint8_t W::sendRadio(char*) no known conversion for argument 1 from 'uint16_t* [3] {aka unsigned int* [3]}' to 'char*'note: uint8_t W::sendRadio(char*)
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: This is no debugging service. See [ask].

Comment: @Olaf , I forgot to set the error sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need this:

```
// define data to send
  char data[20];  // 20 char buffer (should be enough here)

  // Getting Temperature that is 28.75
  float temperature = RTC.getTemperature();

  // HEADER,void float2String(float fl, char str[], int N);
  Utils.float2String (temperature, data, 2);

  USB.println(data);
  // HEADER,sendRadio(char * message)
  error = sendRadio(data);
```

`dataAux` is not needed. `sendRadio` and `println` want a `char*`, and `data` is already a `char*`.

Comment: thanks, I tried that in first place, it does compile, but then I get this on the `serial Temperature: 28.7500000000
Error waiting for packets. error = 1
Temperature: 28.7500000000
Error waiting for packets. error = 1` and according to the function send `1' if there was an error`

Comment: What is `serial Temperature` ?

Comment: According to the send comments `data is a sequence of digit representing the value of byte stream
 *    expressed in hexadecimal value (i.e. radio tx 12A435 – the payload 
 *    is composed by the following byte stream: 0x12, 0xA4, 0x35 – 6 digit
 *    converted in 3 bytes)`

Comment: `serial Temperature` is the display of `float temperature `

Comment: Sorry, I have not enough Arduino knowledge, but the problem is clearly related to `sendRadio`.